How to fetch data from the site that updates in real time as you enter it using IMPORTXML?
I want to import data from https://demonlist.org using this xpath: //a[@href='/classic/1']/descendant::p[1] to a google spreadsheet but it returns that theres no data to import.
I checked the sites source code and turns out its much shorter than when you inspect a specific element. I pretty much dont know anything about web coding but i think its because it updates in real time using javascript. So is there a way to get the data using importxml if thats the case?
